# Identifying user's location by IP address

Tags: php, sql, geolocation, ip

I was writing a program where I wanted the country of the user to be automatically identified. I wrote code that takes the ip and stores it in the DB.

```
$ip = gethostbyname($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Storing:

```
 <?php `$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `wh_order` (`name`, `email`, `contact`, `itemid`, `itemquantity`, `ip`,`message`, `date`) VALUES('".$name."','".$email."','".$contact."','".$itemid."','".$itemquantity."','".$ip."','".$message."', NOW())");` ?>
```

Also, it this the best method of storing ip address?

Comment: Just by storing user's ip how do you identify location?

Comment: There are various APIs out there that can try and suggest a country from an IP however this is not reliable as its not always accurate and the users IP could be blocked or they could be using a VPN. Depending on what you need, you could look at their set locale, however this has the same issues. It would be a best guess.

Comment: Store ip addresses as an int: http://daipratt.co.uk/mysql-store-ip-address/

Comment: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] by itself gives you the IP. You will need to install something like GeoIP from Maxmind in order to get a country code from the IP address.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, gethostbyname won't give you a country. You have to resort to geolocation for that. A free service which works OK is http://freegeoip.net. They provide a API:

http://freegeoip.net/json/74.125.143.104

Which returns:

```
{
    "city": "Mountain View",
    "region_code": "CA",
    "region_name": "California",
    "metrocode": "807",
    "zipcode": "94043",
    "longitude": "-122.057",
    "latitude": "37.4192",
    "country_code": "US",
    "ip": "74.125.227.136",
    "country_name": "United States"
}
```

Note that geolocation by IP wont be 100% accurate.

---

The best column type to store an IP address is `INT(10) unsigned`, which will take up less space than a varchar column. Conversion is easily handled with [INET_ATON](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) and [INET_NTOA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa):

```
mysql> SELECT INET_ATON('10.0.5.9');
        -> 167773449

mysql> SELECT INET_NTOA(167773449);
        -> '10.0.5.9'
```

Comment: @MatthewRiches INET_ATON/INET_NTOA does not currently support IPv6. However, you can use phps inet_pton for this.

Comment: Thankyou. But I didn't understood the "INET_ATON" part. Could you elaborate more? I'm new to this. Thankyou.

Comment: @user1445759 Sure. Use INET_ATON when inserting an IP: `INSERT INTO table(country, ip) VALUES('United States', INET_ATON('10.0.5.9');`. Use INET_NTOA when selecting: `SELECT country, INET_NTOA(ip) from table;`. Makes sense?

Comment: okay. Makes some sense. Similar to Encrypting-Decrypting type. Thanks.

Comment: freegeoip.net sounds nice, didn't know about them. They stopped updating the IP database, though, because IPInfoDB is no longer free.

"The database was last updated in April 29, 2011"

Answer (score 1):

You could use the databases of maxmind (http://www.maxmind.com/app/country) in combination with an apache or nginx extension.

Alternatively, there is a nice library for this task: http://geocoder-php.org/

Answer (score 0):

Identifiying a user's location by their IP is called [Geolocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation). It usually requires a database that maps IP address ranges to geographic locations.

The Maxmind company provides such a database called [GeoLite](https://www.maxmind.com/app/geolite) for free, under a CreativeCommons license

> GeoLite databases are licensed under a Creative Commons
>   Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License. Commercial licensing is
>   available.

They have an apache module that allows for quick IP lookups, the easiest way to get started, however, is probably the pure PHP option. Check out the [list of possible integration methods.](https://www.maxmind.com/app/php)

The download archive includes several example, the basic process is rather straightforward:

```
$gi = geoip_open("GeoLite.dat", GEOIP_STANDARD);
$record = geoip_record_by_addr($gi, "24.24.24.24");
echo $record->latitude;
echo $record->longitude;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the services of https://geoip-db.com They support IPV4 and IPV6 addresses to locate an ip's geolocation.

- JSON: https://geoip-db.com/json
- JSONP: https://geoip-db.com/jsonp

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>GEOIP DB - Geolocation by IP</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Country: <span id="country"></span>
    <div>State: <span id="state"></span>
    <div>City: <span id="city"></span>
    <div>Latitude: <span id="latitude"></span>
    <div>Longitude: <span id="longitude"></span>
    <div>IP: <span id="ip"></span>
    <script>
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://geoip-db.com/jsonp",
            jsonpCallback: "callback",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function( location ) {
                $('#country').html(location.country_name);
                $('#state').html(location.state);
                $('#city').html(location.city);
                $('#latitude').html(location.latitude);
                $('#longitude').html(location.longitude);
                $('#ip').html(location.IPv4);  
            }
        });     
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a jquery snippet, although other examples can be found on their website (Plain javascript, php, C#)